# XElement explicit operator throws an exception when XElement is null

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

`XElement` has explicit operators for nullables. For [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit?view=net-8.0#system-xml-linq-xelement-op-explicit(system-xml-linq-xelement)-system-nullable((system-int32))) `Nullable<Int32>`.

The sample provided by Microsoft appears to accommodate null values in the `WriteLine`, but if you provide a null it throws a `FormatException` and only seems to work if providing a non null value.

```
XElement root = new XElement("Root",   
    new XElement("Value", null)  
);  
int? value = (int?)root.Element("Value");  
Console.WriteLine("Nullable integer: value={0}", value == null ? "null" : value.ToString());
```

The documentation provided by Microsoft seems to suggest a `FormatException` should only occur if:

> The element is not null and does not contain a valid Int32 value.

Have I missed something obvious, or is this not working as designed? Assuming I haven't missed anything is there a convenient way to deal with nullable elements? Currently the best I've come up with is:

```
int? value = Int32.TryParse((string)item.ElementOrException("Value"), out var tempVal) ? tempVal : default(int?);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit?view=net-8.0#system-xml-linq-xelement-op-explicit(system-xml-linq-xelement)-system-nullable((system-int32))):

> The element is not null **and does not contain a valid Int32 value**.

(emphasis mine)

The way it's phrased, even though it's a bit vague, implies that the thing that's allowed to be null is the element, *not* its value, as null is not a a valid int32.

And, indeed, by looking at [the source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XElement.cs,1427):

```
public static explicit operator int?(XElement? element)
{
    if (element == null) return null;
    return XmlConvert.ToInt32(element.Value);
}
```

`XmlConvert.ToInt32` simply calls `int.Parse` with some specific flags.

So, you could say it's a documentation failure, but the behaviour is as designed.

As for a workaround, I guess you could make your own extension method.